# Getting RuntimeException while integrating Admob in Android application

Tags: android, xml, admob

I am new to coding in Android. Recently I made a simple counting app, when I tried to add ads to my app I got a number of errors. I fixed most of them, but here is one I have been facing problem to solve.

Here's (part of) my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        ads:adUnitid="ca-app-pub-8871036677328731/4777520829">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's (part of) my MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "\"ca-app-pub-8871036677328731~4808121041\"");
    mAdView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

And here's (part of) my androidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.courtcounter">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">

    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE">

    </uses-permission>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.ca-app-pub- 
        8871036677328731~4808121041"
                android:value="ca-app-pub-8871036677328731~4808121041" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
            android:value="true"/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here's the error that I am getting:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.courtcounter.MainActivity}:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The adSize and adUnitId must be set before loadAd is called.
```

I was just trying to see if i could add a banner ad to my application. Please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set these two programmatically before you call `loadAd()`

```
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitid="ca-app-pub-8871036677328731/4777520829"
```

like:

```
mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
mAdView.setAdUnitId(YOUR_BANNER_ID);
..
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Honestly, I don't know why xml isn't working as we expect.

Comment: I am getting this error now while trying to run the app.                                      
                                                                                                                           'Android resource linking failed.
C:\Users\JamalHaneef\Downloads\CourtCounter\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:9: error: attribute adUnitid (aka com.example.android.courtcounter:adUnitid) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.'                                                                                      Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: Yes. Try your Ad Unit ID Directly in the Code like this : 'mAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8871036677328731/4777520829");"

Comment: and tell me what happens

Comment: Also. double check your Main AdId in "MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub- 
        8871036677328731~4808121041"); . Hard code this one as well. but when you publish your app these issues should resolve

Comment: Nevermind, I panicked and forgot to delete the AdUnitId from XML. App is running now, but in the actual banner, theres a message "required xml attribute adSize was missing".

Comment: Yeah, I had the same issues. Test your app with a Signed Apk Too, I remember when I used test unitID it was working fine &amp; I had problems with real unitID too.